# Google карты c авто выбором языка

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть сайт, как сделать так, чтобы если пользователь зашёл на сайт с расширением example.com у него показывалась карта на английском языке, а если на example.ru, то на русском

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

function init() {
    // Basic options for a simple Google Map
    // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
    var mapOptions = {
        // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
        zoom: 18,

        // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.734670, 37.604845),

        // Disables the default Google Maps UI components
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scrollwheel: false

    };

    // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
    // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    // Custom Map Marker Icon - Customize the map-marker.png file to customize your icon
    var image = 'images/marker-map.png';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.734670, 37.604845);
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Google Maps API* по-умолчанию берёт информацию о локализации из настроек браузера.

Однако, если требуется изменить язык, то можно добавить необязательный параметр `language` в тег `<script>` при подключении API.

Например *(для японского языка)*:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=ja"
type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Более подробно про локализацию можно почитать в [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?csw=1#Localization).