# Как изменять задать язык google maps в зависимости от просматриваемой местности?

Tags: google-maps

Там похоже адаптивная система и при открытии из русских ОС переводит названия улиц на русский. Хотелось бы видеть названия на том языке, какую страну просматриваешь, т.е. если смотрим на карте на Польшу - улицы на польском, смотрим на Россию - улицы на русском.

Этот вопрос не является дубликатом одного из предложенных, т.к. там показано, как заменить язык не зависимо от позиции на карте.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/560898/186083

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Google карты c авто выбором языка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560888/google-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b-c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: т.е. через iframe это невозможно сделать? Через JS мудрить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22504396/5441700

Comment: @Visman, да так уже лучше) Но я имел ввиду, если смотрим на Польшу - улицы на польском, смотрим на Россию - улицы на русском. Возможно такое?

Comment: Не видел такого варианта.

Comment: Тут, конечно, уже в любом случае JS  будет... Чисто теоретически, по координатам из центра фрейма можно же определить страну? При смене страны через апи перегрузить содержимое с другим языком. Реагировать на прокрутку карты скорее всего тоже можем, надо внимательное почитать доку.

Comment: Я думаю, что с вашим вопросом правильнее обращаться с предложением в гугл:карты - раз. Во-вторых, я не понимаю, как вы собираетесь отображать [страны, в которых более одного языка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2), например Канаду -- два. Я бы предложил вообще отказаться от того, чтобы реализовывать подобную идею.